# XCode C++ SDL 2.0 project to run on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, xcode, translate

I have been using XCode on a Mac to create a simple SDL 2.0 project in C++.

I need to send the **binary** of the project to a company that uses only Windows 7 and allow them to run it without having to fiddle around too much.

The project uses some libraries (https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/) so I am unsure on how to deliver to them something that they can run without having to install stuff.

Ideally I would want to create a binary (targeting Windows 7) which includes the libraries.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

EDIT: I found articles like [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Custom-GCC-and-cross-compilers) suggesting to cross compile but I am still a bit lost on how to start doing this. Will it work? Can it work on both the 32 bit and 64 bits Windows versions?

Comment: I am unsure if XCode binaries will work on a non-Apple platform. I suggest that you rebuild the binary to work with a Windows system, instead of getting a headache.

Comment: Ok. So best thing is to get hold of a Windows 7 machine and open up the source files from there, install the SDL 2.0 library and then create the binary and distribute the latter?

Comment: Exactly the way to go with this.